# How to connect excel to phpMyAdmin database

Tags: php, excel, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to connect Excel to my companies database so any new information/input in the database will automatically refreshes/reflect in the excel sheet.

The connection is between Excel and phpMyAdmin!

Any help?!

Comment: Connecting excel to phpMyAdmin not SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Using triggers and stored procedure this can done.

Create a trigger for the table to load the newly inserted data into a temporary table.

```
create trigger monitorTri on test 
AFTER insert 
as
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tempOfTestInsertion
    SELECT * FROM INSERTED
END
```

and have a stored procedure job to read data from this temp table and write the content in to the required file say for example every 5 mins (depends on your requirement to refresh the content)

Once read operation is done and written in to the required file just truncate the temp table.

Comment: Okay will try this and get back